# Java or Kotlin file `MainApplication.java` does not include package declaration

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av, react-native-unimodules

I was trying to install `expo-av` into a non-expo react-native project. After installing `react-native-unimodules` and adjusting the `android/app/build.gradle` file, I am not able to build the android app anymore.

This is the main error I get:

The terminal looks like this: **Java or Kotlin file `MainApplication.java` does not include package declaration.**

```sh
ENVFILE=.env react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 2152 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 16 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/*REDACTED*/HF-Projects/*REDACTED*/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy' line: 75

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Java or Kotlin file /Users/*REDACTED*/HF-Projects/*REDACTED*/android/app/src/main/java/com/*REDACTED*/MainApplication.java does not include package declaration

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
```

I searched for `package` on that file and found 26 occurrences.

There is this `packages` variable on this `ReactNativeHost` instance.

```java
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          // Add unimodules
          List<ReactPackage> unimodules = Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
          );
          packages.addAll(unimodules);
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

          @Override
          protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
              return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
          }

      };
```

Does anybody know about this error?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

This is a simple validation that looks for the main `package` of that `java` class.
On top of the file, there should be a `package com.yourcompany.example`.

It happened that my `MainApplication.java` class had TWO BLANK SPACES right after packages.

So the regex didn't find it.

The regex used in this validation may be found on the file `node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy` line 67.

Regex used: `/^package ([0-9a-zA-Z._]*);?$/`

```
def readPackageFromJavaOrKotlinFile(String filePath) {
  def file = new File(filePath)
  def fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))
  def fileContent = ""
  while ((fileContent = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
    def match = fileContent =~ /^package ([0-9a-zA-Z._]*);?$/
    if (match.size() == 1 && match[0].size() == 2) {
      fileReader.close()
      return match[0][1]
    }
  }
  fileReader.close()

  throw new GradleException("Java or Kotlin file $file does not include package declaration")
}
```

Comment: thanks exactly my issue 2 blanks between package and package name